# jquery select and text area validation function

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to modify one js file validation rule but unable to do so.

original js code is

```
var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], #first_step input[type=password]');
        var error = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<4 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] ) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        });
```

actually it check for type text and type password but i want it to check for select and text area.

i try to modify password to select and textarea but didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read anything about [how to use jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], #first_step input[type=password]');
```

to

```
var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], 
                #first_step input[type=password],
                #first_step textarea,#first_step select ');
```

If you want to add checking for `select` and `textarea` with your existing code.

And if you want to check for `select` and `textarea` only then use

```
var fields = $('#first_step textarea,#first_step select ');
```

Read more on [Multiple Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and all [`jQuery selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @air do you want to check for `select` and `textarea` only? or all of `text, password, select and textarea` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `fields` as:

```
var fields = $('#first_step textarea, #first_step select');
```

If that doesn't help, provide some sample HTML in your question.